# what is prove the method in reversing the operation symbol in DeMorgan's law?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

For instance, Taking the second DeMorgan's law of set, which we mostly prove as:
(A U B)' = A' ∩ B'

```
Let x be an element such that x ∈ (A U B)'  
so,  
(A U B)' = {x: x ∉ (A U B)}  
         = {x: x ∉ A and x ∉ B}  
         = {x: x ∈ A' ∩ B'}
```

In the above proof we come to a point where the symbol of OR is replaced by AND. How are the symbols easily replaced? Is there a proof for such a functioning of operators, as far as I've been taught by secondary level maths, "It is because there is the **Not belong to symbol**, but now that's not very logical at all.

And do the operators AND and OR relate to the **Boolean operator**?

**EDIT: **I understand from the comments that the operators are really boolean operators then can this line be written as so:

```
From this: {x: x ∉ (A ∩ B)}
              ={x: x ∉ A or x ∉ B}
              which should be equivalent to:
              {x: x ∉ A or x ∉ B or x ∈ (U - (A U B)) }
```

correct me if I'm wrong, please.

Comment: Yes; AND is $\wedge$ and OR is $\vee$. And $\neg(p \vee q)=\neg p \wedge \neg q$.

Comment: for checking if two boolean functions $f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ and $g(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$ are equal, simply test all the $2^n$ possible values of the boolean variables $x_i$, and compare

Answer (score 1):

$x\not\in (A\cup B)$ means that $x$ is not in *either* $A$ *or* $B$.

Because it is in neither, then it is not in $A$ *and* it is not in $B$.

Hence: $(x\notin A){\text{ and }}(x\notin B)$

And vice versa, so:

$$\begin{align}(A\cup B)'
   \iff & \{x: x\not\in A\cup B\}
\\ \iff & \{x: x\notin A~\wedge~x\notin B\}
\\ \iff & A'\cap B' 
\end{align}$$

---

Likewise: If any element is not in $A\cap B$, then it is not in both $A$ and $B$.   So it is either not in $A$ *or* it is not in $B$.   (and vice versa)

$$\begin{align}(A\cap B)'
   \iff & \{x: x\not\in A\cap B\}
\\ \iff & \{x: x\notin A~\vee~x\notin B\}
\\ \iff & A'\cup B' 
\end{align}$$